# How can I verify basic auth using Robolectric?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, http, robolectric

I am using Robolectric, and I can successfully verify that the tested code makes an HTTP call to the correct URL, which is great! However, I am using basic authentication.  Is is possible to verify that the HTTP call was set up with the correct authentication set up?

Comment: In Robolectric you can make real http request and receive real response. It will use internet connection of your computer.

Comment: What do you use URLConnection or HttpClient?

Comment: HttpClient.  Currently I have a "good enough" solution involving switching to preemptive style auth by inserting a header.  To test this, I had to shadow the Base64 class.